# Getting list of friends using the same application in Facebook using Javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, facebook, list

I am extremely new to Facebook API codings and am trying to make a game application where users will be able to see who (in their friend list) is already using the game application. It is pretty much like all the popular Facebook games such as plock, pet society, etc. where users can view their friend's score, profile and ranking in the application.

I've Googled around and searched here for results but most of the methods are using FBML and the REST API which are currently being deprecated. The best I can find are all posts similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028537/getting-list-of-all-friends-on-facebook-using-jssdk-and-fql) which retrieves the full friend list (which is not quite what I'm going for).

I was wondering if there's any way to implement what I want to do with the Graph API -> user_games_activity?

*edit: I forgot to mention that the game is supposed to be integrated in Facebook itself*

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get photo and name from several ids at once](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7289541/how-to-get-photo-and-name-from-several-ids-at-once)

Answer (score 4):

Anytime a user uses your game, make sure their user id is in your database, in your `users` database table for example.

Then, anytime you need to generate the list of the current user's friends who play the game, grab the list of the current user's friends -- see [/me/friends](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) -- and check if any of the returned ids are in your `users` table.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! So does that mean i have to have an external database and i will not be using Facebook's query in anyway?

Comment: Yes, you will need to either maintain an external database as @WayneKao suggests, or get the user ID's in a roundabout way as suggested in my answer below.  Facebook does not support the query "Give me all the users who use my application." unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to maintain a separate database if you store a starting `score` or an `achievement` for each users.  To find friends' Games information, simply get `.../me/friends` for the current User, and then loop through each friend ID returned and query `.../FRIEND_ID/scores` or  `.../FRIEND_ID/achievements` using the User's `access_token`.

Comment: You can also call .../APP_ID/scores to retrieve the list of friends in one API call.

Comment: Note however, that the scores API will only return friends who have set visibility for the app to something wider than "Only Me". Wayne's answer above is a more robust solution, but obviously requires more db infrastructure.

Comment: Good addition @zippycoder Not sure if that functionality was not available at the time -- this *is* two years old -- or if I just overlooked it.  Either way, thanks.~